# What does Low level and High level mean on a Solid State Relay

Tags: solid-state-relay

I wand to control some 220V lights with 12V but don't  want the noise of s normal relay. So I saw these SSR but do not understand what Low level and High level mean.
Is high level normally closed or normally open? And can these be controlled only with 12v? I ask this because they say 12V, but there is a + and a - where i understand you hook up the 12V, what than is has that CH1 input where they say you have to connect 5V to. So I need 12V to operate it and 5V to trigger it?

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-Smart-Electronics-2-Channel-5V-DC-Relay-Module-Solid-State-High-Level-OMRON-SSR/32622381544.html?spm=a2g0s.8937460.0.0.816c2e0eFHD5xA

Comment: "No datasheet? No sale!"

Comment: The English is so poor on that link that it is hard to be confident.